# Cannot Convert 'int' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++, c++builder-xe8

I'm working with c++ and XE8. Given the following code:

```
String __fastcall RemoveCharsFromString(String &str, const String &c)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<c.Length(); ++i)
    {
        str.Delete(std::remove(str[0], str.LastChar(), c[i]), str.LastChar());
    }
}
```

Received errors:

- Using `str.Delete(remove(str[0], str.LastChar(), c[i]), str.LastChar());` results in a

  > Cannot convert 'int' to 'const char *'

  error inside the for loop.
- Using `str.Delete(std::remove(str[0], str.LastChar(), c[i]), str.LastChar());` results in a

  > Could not find a match for 'remove(wchar_t,wchar_t*,wchar_t)'

  error inside the for loop.

Searching SO and the web, it's my understanding this error is usually received when code  is written with single quotes when double quotes should have been used. I don't believe that scenario is applicable in this case.

The return type of `String` is Embarcadero's `UnicodeString`. Details can be found here: [RAD Studio VCL Reference - UnicodeString Class](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__UnicodeString.html)

Comment: What's the `return` type of those `String` member functions and what types are the parameters `String.Delete` accepts?

Comment: My guess is that `str[0]` should simply be `str`, or `&(str[0])` if you like

Comment: Maybe you should show the header for your `String` class since we don't have it. Please edit your question and add the header as text.

Comment: @drescherjm Are you asking for one of the following?
`extern PACKAGE String __fastcall RemoveCharsFromString(String &str, const String &c);` or `typedef UnicodeString        String;`

Comment: Your header for the class `String` that you are writing. It's hard to help without seeing the specifics of your implementation.

Comment: Also show us the code of `remove()`

Comment: Guys, my guess is that `remove` is `std::remove`. And that the other methods are from [this library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.WideString.LastChar).

Comment: @HappyCoding, can you replace `remove` with `std::remove` please, and confirm the problem still occurs? Then, edit the question in the same way.

Comment: @CinCout Added the `remove()` code and source as requested. It can be used by `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: It, in fact, was the `std::remove()` @AaronMcDaid

Comment: For simplicity, I've edited the question to say `std::remove`. There should be no doubt that it is `std::remove` - any confusion will simply make it more difficult for others to join in this discussion. `std::remove` is well known

Comment: @AaronMcDaid replaced `remove` with `std::remove` and received a different error. `Could not find a match for 'remove(wchar_t,wchar_t*,wchar_t)'`

Comment: @HappyCoding, that is a very similar error which confirms that `str[0]` is the issue. It is a character (`wchar_t`), not a string

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I updated the question to reflect the two different scenarios you pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++Builder, `String` refers to `System::String`, which is an alias for [`System::UnicodeString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString) in XE8.

There are a lot of mistakes in your code.

The [`System::String::Delete()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.Delete) method expects an index and a count as input, but that is not what you are trying to pass to it.  You are expecting `Delete()` to work like the STL [`std::wstring::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) method, and that is simply not the case.

You are not taking into account that [`System::String::operator[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.operator_H5BH5D) is 1-based.  It is not 0-based, like your code is assuming.

The [`System::String::LastChar()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.LastChar) method returns a pointer to the last UTF-16 encoded Unicode character in the string.  It does not return a pointer to the string's null terminator, like your code is assuming.

You are calling the STL [`std::remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm that takes a range of `iterator`s as input, shifts all copies of the specified value to the end of the range, and then returns a new `iterator` to where the "removed" values have been moved to within the range (so they can be `erase()`'d from the container that owns the `iterator`s).  You cannot mix `System::String::Delete()` and `std::remove()` the way you are attempting to do.  If you really want to use `std::replace()`, you need to use it more like this instead:

```
String __fastcall RemoveCharsFromString(String &str, const String &c)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= c.Length(); ++i)
    {
        const Char *start = str.c_str();
        const Char* end = start + str.Length();
        Char* ptr = std::replace(start, end, c[i]);
        str.Delete(1 + std::distance(start, ptr), std::distance(ptr, end));
    }
}
```

That being said, Embarcadero's RTL has its own [`System::Sysutils::StringReplace()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StringReplace) function that you can use instead of `std::replace()`:

```
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

String __fastcall RemoveCharsFromString(String &str, const String &c)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= c.Length(); ++i)
    {
        str = StringReplace(str, c[i], L"", TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);
    }
}
```

Or, if you need to take UTF-16 surrogates into account in the `c` string (which `std::remove()` does not account for):

```
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <System.Character.hpp>

String __fastcall RemoveCharsFromString(String &str, const String &c)
{
    int i = 1; 
    while (i <= c.Length())
    {
        String chr;
        if (IsSurrogatePair(c, i))
            chr = c.SubString(i, 2);
        else
            chr = c.SubString(i, 1);
        str = StringReplace(str, chr, L"", TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);
        i += chr.Length(); 
    }
}
```